# SQL: multiple groupings needed to track duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, node_saved_data, setup like this:

set_id - node_id - node_value

The values will look something like

```
2 - 1 - some text
2 - 2 - more text
2 - 3 - a bit more text
2 - 4 - some more text
2 - 5 - even more text
```

I want to see if there are any duplicate node ids within each set. I tried

```
SELECT set_id, node_id, COUNT(node_id) c FROM node_saved_data GROUP BY node_id, set_id
```

but the results were clearly not what I wanted. Any advice? Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I determined I only had to reverse the grouping order I was using. After that It gave me the results I was expecting

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty close. Drop a `HAVING` clause at the end to check for those combinations with more than 1 entry.

```
select 
  set_id, node_id, count(1) 
from 
  node_saved_data 
group by 
  set_id, 
  node_id 
having 
  count(1) > 1
```